# How to approach analysis & correlation of very skewed pair of data sets

Tags: normality-assumption, skewness

I am a stats n00b, so please forgive my ignorance, I'm looking for help in getting started, but I don't know the names of the algorithms to read up on.

I have two datasets which are distinctly NOT normal.

"A" has n=400k and ~25 variables;
"B" has n=8k and ~15 variables

Each row in B corresponds to about 50 rows in A (1-to-many leader-follower). The distributions for most of the variables are very right-skewed. Most actors in A and B tend to do very little, but a small proportion do a great deal, so the distributions have a peak near zero and extremely long tails. E.g. The skew and kurtosis for one of the variables is 16.59 / 585.85.

My objective is to correlate A and B, in particular to see which behaviours in "B" seems to correspond with higher activity in "A". A straight-up Spearman correlation on a similar dataset did show correlations of ~0.3+ for a number of variables in A versus B, and ~0.6+ when looking at the averages of all B for each A.

Can you point me in a direction to further analyse this data? I have been advised to try factor analysis to reduce the number of variables, but I'm struggling with how non-normal the data is. I am about to attempt Box-Cox to transform the data, does that seem a suitable next step? The same Spearman correlation above gave values of ~0.9+ within B versus B, so I do think there is scope to reduce the number of variables.

There is also scope to average the values in A that correspond to the the values in B so that there is a one-to-one relationship rather than 1-to-many. Is this viable? What problems would this introduce?

I am alternatively considering truncating the data to, say, between the 5th to 95th centiles. Is there a way to pick an optimum threshold? This treatment would not be to normalise the data but rather to isolate the area where the interesting behaviour happens (i.e. where non-extreme activity is observed).

Thank you for your help.

- Lnr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, investigate the application of a power transformation to your data, for example, a [Box-Cox Power Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Box%E2%80%93Cox_transformation), which can induce normality and even improve the homogeneity of the variance. In the particular case of [Log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution), the log transform shifts the data to being mean-centered at the average of the logs  (which is now the center of a symmetric Normal distribution).

Also, basing the Pearson correlation on a median (in lieu of the mean) concept is another option to explore. Ssee for example [work here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Median-correlations-Examples-with-correlation-values-around-the-median-value-across-our_fig5_258041434) and also google search on 'Aspects of Linear and Median Correlation Matrix', which is freely available as a pdf.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply